# Find the shortest path with Floyd algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I have an adjacency matrix which contains a number 0s and 1s. If there is no edge from one node to another, the field will 0, otherwise the field will marked as 1.

Then, if a field in the adjacency matrix was 0, there is no edge between nodes, otherwise there is an edge with weight of 1.

Now, I have applied Floyd algorithm to find out the shortest path from any node to each other node. But I don't get the right solution.

Here is my Floyd algorithm implementation.

```
void Floyd_Warshal(int graph[Nodes][Nodes], int D[Nodes][Nodes])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Nodes; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Nodes; j++)
        {
            if (graph[i][j] == 0) { graph[i][j] = INT_MAX; }
            D[i][j] = graph[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < Nodes; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Nodes; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nodes; j++)
            {
                if (D[i][j] > D[i][k] + D[k][j]) {
                    D[i][j] = D[i][k] + D[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have set the 0's as `INT_MAX` in order to build the standard matrix for the algorithm but I didn't get the right solution.

Also, here is an example of my matrix:

```
  A B C D
A 0 0 1 0
B 1 1 0 1
C 0 0 1 0
D 1 0 0 0
```

After applying the matrix to the algorithm, any 0 in the matrix will be converted to the `INT_MAX`. I expect to get the weight as 2's or 1's but I get unexpected values such as -2712323...

Comment: can you attach an example adjacency matrix as well?

Comment: ...and the expected output and the output you get. Also could you clarify what do you mean with "If there is not any edge from a particular node to **any other nodes**, the field will 0, otherwise the field will marked as 1."

Comment: @ralzaul I have updated the post to add the example.

Comment: @Petr I mean that for example if there is not any edge between node A to node C, the value of A-C in the matrix will be 0 else the value will be 1.

Comment: @VCL_D, I've reworded you question a bit so that it is more clear, because when you same "any other nodes", this looks like you mean *all* other nodes, not just a particular other node corresponding to that element in adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you get very big negative values is integer overflow.

If there is no edge, you set `D[i][j]=INT_MAX`. But then

```
            if (D[i][j] > D[i][k] + D[k][j]) {
                D[i][j] = D[i][k] + D[k][j];
```

if there is no edge from `i` to `k` and from `k` to `j`, then the sum will overflow and the result will be negative. Afterwards, you algorithm will think that there is a very short (large negative) path from this `i` to this `j`, and this will poison all other paths.

I suggest you using `INT_MAX/2` instead if `INT_MAX`.

Comment: (or write the test as `if (D[i][j] - D[k][j] > D[i][k]) {`, which cannot overflow assuming nonnegative distances.)